# Sharepoint 2010: Rearranging the list of employee in the employee directory based on certain field values

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

Is there a way I can rearrange the list of employees shown in the employee directory page based on certain field values of each employee.

Currently, am using javascript/jquery to rearrange using insertBefore and insertAfter, but am not able to fetch the entire div tag to place before another div tag. Any suggestions would be helpful.

// If the job title is in the list of managerTitles, make this person the first in the list if they're not aready first

```
    if($.inArray(jobTitle3, managerTitles) >= 0) {
                // If they're not first in the list, move them there"
                if(personIndex > 0) {
                    // Move the manager to first
                    $(this).insertBefore($('.psrch-FullResult:first'));
                }

                // Insert a block div to create a line break after the manager
                $("<div style='display:block;clear:both;'></div>").insertAfter($('.psrch-FullResult:first'));

            }
```

$(this) represents the current object. But I don't see any change in the result being displayed. Any suggestions

When a condition is satisfied, I want to move the entire div before all of them and show it on the top and seperate this from the other with a div tag.

Comment: Pleas update your previous question rather than starting a new one that is essentially a complete duplicate

Comment: Hi, I raised this as a new question as I would like to know if any of the sharepoint properties are blocking to rearrange the div in the list of employee div's. or is there any limitation on using $(this).insertBefore($('.psrch-FullResult:first')) in sharepoint 2010 where $(this) represents the current object. But I don't see any change in the result being displayed. Any suggestions. 
When a condition is satisfied, I want to move the entire div before all of them and show it on the top and seperate this from the other with a div tag.